# falied when create a dataset using tf.data.dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I try to obtain dataset using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` but I got:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
   train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train['email'].values, train['label'].values))
   valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validation['email'].values, validation['label'].values))
```

and the `train['email'].values` is a string ndarray

Comment: Have you checked your data for NaN values?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have mixed  datatype in your input dataset like string and float values.

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
x_train = ['abc@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com','aaa@gmail.com','abd@gmail.com']
y_train = ['0','1','0','1']

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([x_train,y_train])
for element in dataset:
  print(element)
```

**Output**

```
tf.Tensor([b'abc@gmail.com' b'xyz@gmail.com' b'aaa@gmail.com' b'abd@gmail.com'], shape=(4,), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor([b'0' b'1' b'0' b'1'], shape=(4,), dtype=string)
```